# Remove colored box of \ref locally

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a theorem A and another one whose numbering is the numbering of A followed by a prime. However, I don't want the red box of the numbering for the second theorem, and this is the single place where I want to remove the box, that is, I want to keep the boxes for all other references. The example I have is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newenvironment{thmprime}[1]
{\renewcommand{\thethm}{\ref{#1}$'$}%
\addtocounter{thm}{-1}%
\begin{thm}}
{\end{thm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{test}
Test
\begin{align}\label{eqn} 
a^2 
\end{align}
\end{thm}

Equation \ref{eqn}

\begin{thmprime}{test}
Test
\end{thmprime}

\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\ref*` in

```
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\ref*{#1}$'$}%
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newenvironment{thmprime}[1]
{\renewcommand{\thethm}{\ref*{#1}$'$}%
\addtocounter{thm}{-1}%
\begin{thm}}
{\end{thm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{test}
Test
\begin{align}\label{eqn}
a^2
\end{align}
\end{thm}

Equation \ref{eqn}

\begin{thmprime}{test}
Test
\end{thmprime}

\end{document}
```

[image]